# Google App Script - loop using fetch to get API response and write in spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a script which loops a list of 50-100 queries to the YouTube API to obtain results and then store these results in a sheet.  The next step will be to take the results from the query and insert them into a MySQL database.

I have an existing spreadsheet with two columns; name and query.  Name is for reference only.  Query is the important column, which has the entire query string that needs to be used with fetch.

I have confirmed the queries work and I can call them and see the results with no issue.  I can obtain the list of URLs from my spreadsheet, but I cannot figure out how to make a loop to execute the queries and then write the results to another spreadsheet.

I am definitely no expert so I am sure I am missing some basic logic here.

I start with gathering the queries from my reference sheet and validating I am seeing the correct results.

```
function listYTChannels() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("YTChannel");
  var sheetLR = sheet.getLastRow();
  var data = sheet.getRange(1,2,sheetLR).getValues();
  
  data.forEach(function (row) {
    Logger.log(row);
  });
}
```

Then I can validate my fetch is working correctly.

```
function testquery() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet,contentDetails,brandingSettings&key=SECRETSTUFF&id=NOTSECRETBUTUNIQUE");
Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Here I'm stuck.  I don't know how to use forEach (or another loop method) to execute fetch with a unique query (which is listed in my YTChannel sheet) for each of the rows I obtain, and then store the results in another sheet.

This is where I am stuck.  What's a good way to have fetch execute on each row of my existing sheet and then write the results to a new sheet?

Thank you in advance for any answers!!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: @Cooper, you're suggesting to populate const array1 with data from YTChannel, and then use forEach(callbackFn) to execute fetch for each result?  Apologies if this is a bit obvious of a question, but I am just learning this stuff.  Thanks!!

Comment: All I'm saying is that saying that you don't know how to use forEach method is easily solved by you taking the time and effort to learn how to use it yourself.  The assumption on this site is that you already know Javascript.  If you don't then it's your responsibility to do the learning to make up that deficiency.

Comment: Fair enough.  Thanks for your input and time, it's definitely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
  function listYTChannels2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("YTChannel");
  const otherSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1FdghGqGxRb')
                     .getSheetByName('otherSheet')
  var sheetLR = sheet.getLastRow();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  data.forEach(function (row,index) {
  Logger.log(row);
  // var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(row);
  // Logger.log(response.getContentText());
   console.log(index);
   otherSheet.getRange(index+1,1,1,row.length).setValues([row]);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful!  I still kept getRange instead of getDataRange because otherwise it returns the first column in the YTChannel sheet, which is not required for the query.

My query then becomes:
function listYTChannels() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("YTChannel");
  var sheetLR = sheet.getLastRow();
  var data = sheet.getRange(1,2,sheetLR).getValues();
  
  data.forEach(function (row) {
    Logger.log(row);

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(row);
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  });
}
Works great!  How to write to a sheet?

Comment: I edited the answer, maybe it will give you a hint

Comment: That helps immensely, thank you very much!